# How do I add parenthesis to this rule?

Tags: antlr, parentheses, lexical-analysis

I have a left-recursive rule like the following:

```
EXPRESSION      :    EXPRESSION BINARYOP EXPRESSION | UNARYOP EXPRESSION | NUMBER;
```

I need to add parenthesis to it but I'm not sure how to make a left parenthesis depend on a matching right parenthesis yet still optional. Can someone show me how? (Or am I trying to do entirely too much in lexing, and should I leave some or all of this to the parsing?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a recursive rule:

```
EXPRESSION      : EXPRESSION BINARYOP EXPRESSION
                | UNARYOP EXPRESSION
                | NUMBER
                | OPENPARENS EXPRESSION CLOSEPARENS
                ;
```

Comment: Sorry, the rule's name is actually `EXPRESSION`, i realized that just a minute ago.

Comment: @RCIX: you sure about that? AFAIK, that won't work: ANTLR cannot handle  such *left-recursive* rules. See: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Left-Recursion+Removal

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're trying to do too much in the lexer. Here's how to get around the left-recursive rules:

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Expression+evaluator (see how the parser rule `expr` trickles down to the rule `atom` and then get called recursively from `atom` again)

HTH

Comment: Oh dear this is going to be big... Thanks for the tip though!